# how to load a file in mysql tables column?

Tags: mysql, file, load

I need to set one column's value which would be big scss file with lots of characters (thats why I cant just `UPDATE TABLE table WHERE value = 'very big txt file'`). So I found that I can use msyql function `LOAD_FILE('/loc/to/bigfile.scss')` Full command looks like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET value = LOAD_FILE('/path/to/bigfile.scss')
WHERE
name = 'my_theme' ;
```

column 'value' cannot be null and mysql gives me error:

```
ERROR 1048 (23000) at line 1: Column 'value' cannot be null
```

Which means that this LOAD_FILE didn't work.
file location is 100 % correct.
Could you help me?

Comment: use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html  to import the data into a temporary table and use that to update. But first you have to insert the data from the file

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way is to use '**LOAD DATA INFILE**'

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'bigfile.scss' 
INTO TABLE employee
(value);
```

Official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) and  more examples of these [here.](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/11/mysql-load-data-infile/)

Comment: but I cannot find how I can find that particular value because It seems that I cant use WHERE statement here. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you can't you can change the received data during insert see my comment